# Dynamically generating Django Form Classes, What's the best way to remedy circular import?

Tags: python, django, forms

I wrote a short snippet to dynamically generate all of my model forms within an app. To me, the most logical place to call this snippet is in the app's forms.py. But this causes a circular import since I'm trying to set attributes in the module that called me, and it doesn't exist yet.  Is there an elegant way around this?

## #bomgar.forms.py

```
import base.forms
import bomgar       # bomgar is myapp

base.forms.generate_base_forms(bomgar)
```

## #base.forms.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
import inspect


class BaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    class Meta:
        model=None


''' Generates a base set of forms to work off of. So I dont have to
    make a billion of them by hand to start off. '''
def generate_base_forms(module):
    __import__('%s.models' % module.__name__)
    __import__('%s.forms' % module.__name__)    
    for model_name, model_class in inspect.getmembers(module.models):
        if inspect.isclass(model_class):
            if model_class._meta.abstract == False:
                form_name=model_name+'Form'
                class ModelMeta(BaseForm.Meta):
                    model=model_class
                form_class=type(form_name,(BaseForm,), { 'Meta': ModelMeta })
                setattr(module.forms, form_name, form_class)
```

## Terminal Output

```
(env)Macbook:djinmanage me$ ./manage shell
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import bomgar.models
>>> import bomgar.forms
<module 'bomgar.models' from '/Users/me/Sites/djinmanage/djinmanage/bomgar/models.pyc'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/Sites/djinmanage/djinmanage/bomgar/forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    base.forms.generate_base_forms(bomgar)
  File "/Users/me/Sites/djinmanage/djinmanage/base/forms.py", line 19, in generate_base_forms
    print module.forms
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'forms'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function to generate the forms at the *end* of the module, after all the required names have been bound.

**EDIT:**

Okay, you imported them. But you let the imports fall on the floor.

```
impmodule = __import__('%s.models' % module.__name__)
__import__('%s.forms' % module.__name__)    

   ...

    setattr(impmodule.forms, form_name, form_class)
```

(You don't need to catch the result of the second `__import__` since they're both the same module.)

Comment: A calls a method in B. and B tries to set attributes on A.  A isn't a module object to set attributes on yet though.
If I move the function call into another file, it'd be fine.

Comment: A is a module as soon as it's imported. Ever.

Comment: I'll admit I'm still a newbie at python. But I'm still pretty sure it's because of a circular import. I updated my code to reflect verbatim what's in my files.  forms.py exists right next to models.py, so it's not something silly like the file doesn't exist.

Comment: That is a *completely different problem*.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not entirely sure what the issues with the imports were. Django seems to import your models.py file for free, but not forms or views. But I solved what I was trying to do. I think the trick was to `__import__('xyz', fromlist=[*])`

This will generate all your model forms for all your installed django apps if they extend a specified class(I called mine base.models.BaseClass). You could target django.db.models.Model as the parent class, but I don't know what extends that, so you may make a bunch of forms you don't want.  Maybe someone will find this snippet useful.

```
import inspect

def get_module_classes(module):
    '''
    Returns a list of classes that aren't abstract for the given module.
    '''
    class_list = []
    for model_name, klass in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.isclass(klass) and hasattr(klass, '_meta') and klass._meta.abstract == False:
            class_list.append(klass)
    return class_list


'''
Searches your installed apps and creates a model form for every model that extends base.models.BaseObject.
The new form class is put in it's appropriate app.forms module. If the class name already exists(you defined it yourself),
then the new class is not generated. 
'''    
import types
import settings
import base.models
import base.forms
for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    try:
        models_module = __import__(app+'.models', fromlist=['*'])
        forms_module = __import__(app+'.forms', fromlist=['*'])
        for model_class in get_module_classes(models_module):
            if issubclass(model_class, base.models.BaseObject):
                form_name = model_class.__name__+'Form'
                ModelMeta = types.ClassType('ModelMeta', (base.forms.BaseForm.Meta, ), { 'model': model_class })
                FormClass = type(form_name, (base.forms.BaseForm, ), { 'Meta': ModelMeta })
                if not hasattr(forms_module, form_name):
                    setattr(forms_module, form_name, FormClass)
    except ImportError:
        pass
```